# Three.js: Web GL errors loading 3d json file - GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION

Tags: json, three.js, blender

Trying to load a 3d .json file of a Lamborghini into three.js, using the object loader. It should be loading file but I'm getting the following web GL errors:

```
THREE.ObjectLoader: Undefined texture null
65localhost/:1 [.WebGLRenderingContext-0x100537f00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
191localhost/:1 [.WebGLRenderingContext-0x100537f00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : glFramebufferTexture2D: <- error from previous GL command
```

It doesn't give me anything else but the above, doesn't tell me which texture is null even :(

How can I fix these errors and successfully import this json file? I think it's something with my json file formatting. :(

[Here's my code demo](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/4/) 
([and the json model file](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/4/models/lamborghini-aventador-pbribl.json)).

Comment: running on chrome your demo code runs just fine with no errors. it does take some time for the model to load.

Comment: Ah thanks good to know. I'm on OSX 10.6.8, sometimes Web GL seems to be a bit funky when there's lots to render on this OS. Maybe it's time to upgrade :)